# Selenium Java Junit - Assert if the result is greater than 1000

Tags: java, string, selenium, junit, assert

I am using Java Junit to verify the search result if greater than 1000

but Selenium can only storeText which is (String)

Than I try to convert (String) to (Int)

So that I can compare the search result(String) to 1000.

However, it doesn't work.

Also, I am not sure if I use assetThat in the right way.

Anyone knows the answer please help!

Thank you!

In Java code:

```
    String result = selenium.getText("css=span.rcnt");
    System.out.println("Search result is: " + result);

    int foo = Integer.parseInt(result);

    assertThat("Pass", foo, greaterThan(1000));
```

Comment: What is wrong with `assertThat(foo > 1000)`? Also, can you be a little more specific, rather than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: For example, capture the result using xPath. as                                       String result = selenium.getText("//html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/h1/span[1]");

Comment: Then converting the string to int:                                                          int s = Integer.parseInt(result);                                                     System.out.println("test: " + s); //However, it doesn't print s as integer or anything

Comment: Please add the error message from JUnit.

Comment: I found the solution. The value I got from xPath is String and there's comma in the number. So I need to split the String into each char, and finally convert it into Integer. Thanks anyway, Stefan.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use asserThat, preferring assertTrue.

However I see from link below that assertTrue has only two arguments:

http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/

Try:

```
 assertThat(foo, greaterThan(1000);
```

Comment: I think I found the problem there's nothing to do with assert. But thank you anyways!